# Why is google.com not opening for me?

Tags: windows-xp, browser, internet-connection

I'm having this weird problem where only google.com and Google's subdomains are not opening.
I'm using Chrome, though the same behaviour is prevalent in IE8.

Seems name resolution for google.com fails, as get an error message

> Error 105 (net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED): The server could not be found

However I *can* ping google.com

> Pinging google.com [74.125.227.18] with 32 bytes of data:
>
> Reply from 74.125.227.18: bytes=32 time=60ms TTL=47
>
> Reply from 74.125.227.18: bytes=32 time=33ms TTL=47
>
> Reply from 74.125.227.18: bytes=32 time=32ms TTL=47
>
> Reply from 74.125.227.18: bytes=32 time=62ms TTL=47
>
> Ping statistics for 74.125.227.18:

```
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
```

> Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:

```
Minimum = 32ms, Maximum = 62ms, Average = 46ms
```

This seems to be localized on my laptop & Google, since I can access other pages and Google on other systems just fine.
I have cleared the DNS cache, reset my network settings - none of these have helped.

HOSTS file has an entry just for `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I'm using Windows XP.

Comment: Did you ping google.com and let the name resolve itself or did you put in the ip address?

Comment: Also have you tried a different user on the same laptop?

Comment: @JNK: It was ping google.com.

Comment: did  you try a different user on the same laptop?

Comment: FWIW @JNK the only other user was the Admin user and I do not have the password to login to that account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fiddling with this for more than hour - including flushing the DNS cache, disable & renable wireless, connect a network cable  ( all of which didn't help) , I visited the site by directly entering the IP address. That about still did not resolve my problem of not being able to visit other google pages and subdomains.

I did a test search and now everything seems to be working fine :-\

Comment: Waaaaaaaaaah?  If it works, I guess, don't touch it! ;)

Comment: Yeah @JNK I'm still baffled.

Comment: When you say you are flushing the DNS Cache, you are probably taking about the operating system cache. However I read that Chrome uses its own DNS Caching (they say that is one of the reasons it was fast) and possibly IE 8 has followed suit.

Comment: @sgmoore: That would explain it, I guess.